# Enity Framework overriding identity column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Code First EF class like so:

```
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    /* snip */
}
```

and what I want to happen is when the ID property is null or 0 the database will generate an ID value for it, however if I explicitly set this value so `newEvent.ID=10000000`, it will use that as the ID column, currently doing that will result in the next available ID.

Answer (score 1):

To start, I am not aware of a good solution for this. I recommend you rethink what you are trying to do, or explain further why you need to do this. There's probably a better solution. The only solution I know of for what you want is ugly, and I can't really recommend it.

1. You cannot use an identity (auto-increment) field. If you put this
   on your column, then there is just nothing you can do. Your database
   will either throw an error, or ignore values you give it.
2. You will have to handle the auto-increment yourself. There are many
   ways to do this (store the current value in the database, perform a
   max() query, etc).
3. You'll probably be tempted to override SaveChanges(). [Here is an SO
   POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080588/entity-framework-dbcontext-override-savechanges-for-each-model) about that. I really do not recommend you do this either.

Perhaps someone will come along with a really awesome solution for you. Sorry, I know this was more of a non-answer for you. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I would ideally not like to do it this way either. The idea behind this is implementing the PUT HTTP Method (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) where if a PUT request is sent for a resource (http://example.com/resource/400 for example) a resource should be created at that address. Perhaps I have misinterpreted this

Comment: I would do it this way: Leave your auto-increment field alone and make a UserID field (or whatever) and set the value on that field instead.

Comment: and manually generate ID's for objects that do not supply it?

Comment: Your choice. You could manually set it, or you could set it as the same as the autoincremented field in that case. This is assuming you even need to allow users to specify their IDs. As in, have this instead (example.com/resource/MyUserName) in which case you only have an auto-increment field and don't even mess with manually populating the ID.

Comment: hmmmm interesting idea, I will have a look at what I can do, Thanks for your input :)